# Linked Lists and Trees

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list

Final Question/Post on this! I'm pretty close now I think!

Basically, A Tree, where each node contains a List of numbers, where the tree is sorted by the name (data contained within the tree node). Essentially, at the moment, I have so my name is added to my tree, and that tree's list, is given the number, but I am trying to work towards the ability of each name having multiple numbers, thus the linked list expands if two of the same names are entered with different numbers. I have the compare code in place to check for the same name, but at that point, I am unsure how to modify my pointers, so that I add another element to my list, and add the new number there.

Cheers, any help/tips/clues etc are much appreciated

Below is my current code:

EDIT: The question is really, how I now, take the code I have, and allow the list of each TreeNode to contain multiple numbers, when the same name of a previous treenode is entered, thus building a list of numbers for that name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    char            *number;
    struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct TreeNode {
    char            *name;
    ListNode        *numbers;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
}TreeNode;

TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *, char *, char *);
TreeNode* SearchTree(TreeNode *root, char *search);
int N_Print(TreeNode *root);

int main(void) {
    char my_string[50], name[25], number[25];
    TreeNode *root = NULL;
    while ((fgets(my_string, 50, stdin)) != NULL) {
        if (my_string[0] == '.')
            break;      
        sscanf(my_string, "%s %s", name, number); 
        root = AddNode(root, name, number);  
    }   
    N_Print(root);
    return 0;
}

TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *root, char *name, char *number) {
    int comparison;
    if ( root == NULL) {
        root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        root->numbers = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        root->name = strdup(name); root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
        root->numbers->next = NULL;
    }else if (( comparison = strcmp(name, root->name)) < 0 )
        root->left = AddNode(root->left, name, number);
    else if (comparison > 0) {
        root->right = AddNode(root->right, name, number);
    } else if (comparison == 0 ) {
        root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
        root->numbers->next = NULL;
    }
    return root;
}

TreeNode* SearchTree(TreeNode *root, char *search) {
    int comparison;
    if (root == NULL) {
        printf("NOT FOUND\n");
        return NULL;
    } else if ((comparison = stricmp(search, root->name)) == 0) {
        return root;
    } else if ((comparison = stricmp(search, root->name)) < 0) {
        return SearchTree(root->left, search);
    } else if ((comparison = stricmp(search, root->name)) > 0) 
        return SearchTree(root->right, search);    
}

int N_Print(TreeNode *root) {
    TreeNode *search_val;
    char search[25];
    while(1) {
        printf("Type a name please: ");
        scanf("%24s", search);
        if (search[0] == '.')
            break;
        search_val = SearchTree(root, search); 
        if (search_val == NULL) {
            N_Print(root);
        }
        printf("%s\n", search_val->numbers->number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My first guess is that the code I need to add, needs to be placed within my compare IF statement when the result of compare == 0, thus increment the list, and add the number there. But this is where I'm stuck!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Please re-tag if so.

Comment: Could you form this into a specific question?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read entirely through your code as it made my eyes glaze...

This is your struct that holds the numbers.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    char            *number;
    struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;
```

If a name is to have multiple numbers, you should declare it like this.

```
char            **number;
```

So that the first pointer ***(**number+0)* is the first number for that name, and then **(**number+0) is the next. This would look neater as a linked list so i suggest structuring it like that, and then iterating through the list until you hit null to get all the possible numbers for that name.

Answer (score 0):

As this thread contains most of your code, I thought it was best to respond here.

To make your code work, you need to change the code within the "IF statement" of your function `AddNode` when `comparison == 0`, which you have already pointed out.

```
TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *root, char *name, char *number) {
int comparison;
if ( root == NULL) {
    root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    root->numbers = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    root->name = strdup(name); root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
    root->numbers->next = NULL;
}else if (( comparison = strcmp(name, root->name)) < 0 )
    root->left = AddNode(root->left, name, number);
else if (comparison > 0) {
    root->right = AddNode(root->right, name, number);
} else if (comparison == 0 ) {

    // Create a new ListNode 
    newListNode = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    newListNode -> number = strdup(number);

    // Add newListNode to existing list
    newListNode -> next = root -> numbers;
    root -> numbers = newListNode;
}
return root;
}
```

You should probably also adjust your `SearchTree` function, so that it returns the list of phone numbers.